# Best way to match text between tags with attributes

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, dom

I am trying to get all text between two tags. There will be more than one tags pairs in the document, so I need to get all entries.

Here is an example of text

```
<pre class="code-class" id="code-error">
function error_notice() {
    ?>
    <div class="error notice">
        <p><?php _e( 'There has been an error', 'my_textdomain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_error_notice' );
</pre>
```

As you can see there is nested code inside `<pre>` tag has HTML itself, but I need to capture all text between `<pre>` tags. Also I want to parse attributes `class` and `id` for example.

I tried to parse this text using `DOMDocument`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
$preTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('pre');
foreach($preTags as $pre)
{
```

But nested HTML parsed as separate node.

I also tried using regex, but cannot parse all possible attributes.

Please suggest the best way to parse and consider all possible cases.

Comment: This `<pre class="code-class" id="code-error">
function error_notice() {
    ?>` looks like invalid PHP. Is this your actual code or is this trimmed down and pre-page execution?

Answer (score 5):

Use this to capture all content inside pre tag:

```
<pre.*?>(.*?)<\/pre>
```

capture group 1 contains the content that you are looking for

Try this regex over the entire string and get the classes and ids as for each match in capture group 1

```
class="(.*?)"|id="(.*?)"
```

[Try here](https://regex101.com/r/3VmRQJ/3)

[Run the php sample here](http://ideone.com/c6jcXO)

Comment: I wouldn't say a regex is the `best approach` with HTML.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but as it was mentioned in previous comment, regex may lead to performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

```
$input_lines= YOUR CODE;
preg_match_all("/<pre[^>]*>(.*?)<\/pre>/is", $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

demo http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hSB